# Where to edit page links - Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Hey guys I am trying to figure out where I can edit my links to pages for Joomla.  I recently just switched server over and transfered site but I am trying to get rid of this link:

```
thesite.com/index.php/home/2013-08-03-07-53-09/home-page-4-one-page
```

So that now it is just:

```
thesite.com/
```

Suggestions, thoughts?

UPDATED:

More so the question I am asking, the `home-page-4-one-page` file that is being grabbed here I want to make that so its located at the root and not all the way `/index.php/home/2013-08-03-07-53-09/home-page-4-one-page`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Joomla usage and not programming, it would be better asked on http://joomla.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

For making this specific page the default (home page) of your website, you need to set this menu item as the default menu item of the site.

To get rid of the index.php, you need to enable URL rewriting in global configuration and rename the htaccess.txt file in your joomla root folder to .htaccess and un-comment the Rewrite Base rule.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Joomla administrator->Menu manager.

Edit Home link and update it's alias.

It will resolve the issue.

Comment: I am not sure, this was a project I came into, is there a way I can check?